# JQuery AutoComplete with Spring MVC Returning List, but Not Filtered

Tags: java, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring app that I want to implement the autocomplete feature in JQuery.  If I have a local Array it works perfectly and filters the list while I enter values in the input box.  If I change it to use a data source, it returns the list but does not filter the list based on the entry of the input box.

I have read the Jquery UI tutorial many times and have used the examples located at http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-autocomplete-json-tutorial/
and http://blog.m1key.me/2011/10/jquery-ui-autocomplete-spring-mvc.html but I still can't find a definitive answer why does the local array values get filtered automatically but a returned list doesn't?

I can get it working by filtering myself in my query but since it filters with the local array I figured it would do the same for a list that is returned from the db.

Am I doing something wrong?  Should the list from the db be filtered the same way as the local Array is?

Comment: Please post your code. Hard to say what's wrong without it.

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getProductAutoCompleteList.do", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=*/*")
    public @ResponseBody List<String> getProductAutoComplete(@RequestParam("term") String prodName, HttpServletResponse response){
        logger.info("getProductAutoCompleteList called with parameter: " + prodName);
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        final List<String> productList = ProductSearchHelper.getProductAutoCompleteList(prodName);


        response.setContentType("application/json");
        return productList;
    }
```

Make sure you

1. specify response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
2. optional, setContentType as application/json, having @ResponseBody annotation, Spring MVC invokes a MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter built on the Jackson JSON processor. This implementation is enabled automatically when you use the mvc:annotation-driven configuration element with Jackson present in your classpath.